# Hex Bar Deadlift: Should my upper back be sore?

Tags: deadlifts, legs, muscle-soreness, back-pain, back

Not sure how I can elaborate on the title - thanks for input.

Comment: can you add your experience: how long have you been lifting? what is the weight you deadlifting?  Do you feel sore doing other exercises?

Comment: I was deadlifting 150 pounds (60 bar and 2 plates). Yes I get sore doing other exercises, my routine hasn't been consistent until the past month or  so... so I still get sore from exercises, not too badly, but this upper back soreness from deadlifting (which has been the past 2 or 3 times), has been more intense than after I do rows + pullups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, upper back soreness from any deadlift is perfectly normal.

Keep in mind, the weight is hinged on your shoulders. That's where it is attached to your torso. When you bend forward, you have to pull your shoulders back/up in order to not have them pulled down. Your upper back muscles are involved in bracing your shoulders, so it's only natural that you feel the effects of that engagement.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if I should flex as you described, perfect.

Comment: @Jazzie3 - Oh yes, definitely. You can get quite a bit of neck pain as a result of letting your shoulders just slump forward with the weight, as it pulls heavily on the muscles in that area.